Setting border opacity for disabled textfields in Material UI
I would like to set the border opacity on my disabled MUI textfields. Right now they are darker than I'd like them to be. I'm trying the code below, but haven't had any success. I'm not sure what I'm missing. The other style rules are applying, so I know I have the theme set up correctly. I'm currently trying to apply to those with the "outlined" variant, but applying universally to inputs would be acceptable as well.
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: 'outlined',
      },
    },
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        notchedOutline: {
          '&[disabled]': {
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#89D329',
    },
  },
});

